# Is there any relation between the prime factors of two addends and the prime factors of the sum?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For example for a sum of $27 (3^3)$, one has addends
$2 ( 2^1)$    and $25 ( 5^2)$;
$3 ( 3^1)$    and $24 ( 2^3 \times 3 )$;
......
$12 (2^2 \times 3)$ and $15 (3 \times  5)$;
$13 ( 13^1 )$  and $14 (2 \times 7)$;

Comment: $27 = 3^3{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Let $r=s+t$. If $r$ shares a prime factor with either one of $s,t$ then it shares that factor with the other one as well. Other than that, no useful relation is known. For example, we know perfectly well the prime factorizations of $2^{2^n}$ and of $1$, but that tells us next to nothing about the prime factorization of $2^{2^n}+1$.

Answer (score 0):

That's the ABC conjecture,
called  "the most important unsolved problem in Diophantine analysis".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture